# How do you programmatically save an excel chart as interactive web page using Perl?

Tags: perl, ole, excel-2003

For example:
Consider a chart in cell F11 of sheet1 in workbook1. How to select the chart area in sheet1 and save it as an interactive web page. The "Illustration 2" in the following link shows how to save a excel chart as interactive web page manually. I want to achieve the same in Perl programming.

http://www.trinity.edu/rjensen/dhtml/excel01.htm

Comment: "Interactive Web Page" in this case appears to mean "Workbooks containing one worksheet with one interesting thing on it" … so it can be opened with the Excel for Internet Explorer plug-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can produce Excel 2000 style interactive web pages with Perl using [Spreadsheet::WriteExcelXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcelXML/).

See [this example that I posted in Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=444339) in 2005, which is [also included in the examples](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcelXML-0.13/examples/web_component.pl) directory of the Spreadsheet::WriteExcelXML distro.

However, there are some major caveats:

- Spreadsheet::WriteExcelXML doesn't support charts (they weren't supported in the Spreadsheet XML format).
- These interactive webpages require an "Office **2003** Office Web Components" plugin which is available for Internet Explorer only.
- Interactive web pages aren't supported by Excel 2007 or later. It is a dead technology.

So, it is probably best looking for some other way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Excel 2003 style interactive web pages was chosen because it supports charts. I want to view the web page only in Internet explorer.

Comment: @laksh In that case you could export an interactive webpage with a chart from Excel and use it as a template. You could then use Spreadsheet::WriteExcelXML to replace the data part (as shown in the example linked above). The chart part is separate from the data part. You could leave the chart part as it is or you could replace elements programmatically (for example to extend the axis ranges).

Comment: @laksh Alternatively, if you are on Windows you could use Win32::OLE to export the interactive webpages dynamically from Excel.